# What is the problem of adding .dispose() after .subscribe()

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

After going through some discussions about when to dispose a `CompositeDisposable`, I wonder why we can't just add a `.dispose()` after `.subscribe()` in code.

```
Observable.just(0)
    .doOnNext{...}
    .subscribe()
    .dispose()
```

What is actually happen if the code is like this? Is it ok to write like this? (instead of `.addTo(compositeDisposable)`)

Comment: not 100% sure but `.dispose()` will kill the subsription so your subscriber will never get called . Use `.dispose()` when you don't want the subscription any more .

Comment: Because it will dispose your flow as soon as subscribe returns, which may or may not give enough time to run an flow with asynchronous steps (before a `subscribeOn` for example). Adding it to a composite will tie it to some lifecycle/scope which will then dispose the flow sometime after.

Comment: @akarnokd I realise that it's true. I experienced the `doOnNext` can still execute because the task is small and complete before being disposed. Adding to `CompositeDisposable` should be the valid way.

Answer (score 0):

after you called dispose it will not propagate result to the subscribers anymore

so you should dispose your disposable as soon as this observable stopped to emit values like below

```
fun Disposable?.disposeIfNotNullAndNotDisposed() {
    if (!(this == null || this.isDisposed)) this.dispose()
}
```

Comment: with this code, if it doesn't dispose, then it never will dispose